# How to convert linked list to C++ vector (why doesn't this code work?)

Tags: c++, stl

I have some legacy code that uses an explicitly linked-list to hold an event list that is periodically looped through.  Instead of defining a 'next' pointer in each event-node, I thought a vector would be more compact & more efficient, however, the conversion of something I thought to be straight forward, has me going in circles.  I reduced the problem to 1 file and a smaller subset of code that uses a conditional '#define' to compile the LL version or the vector version.  While LL version compiles, I can't get the STL version that ***looks*** like it should should be equivalent, to cleanly compile.

Here's the test code:

```
#define dummy_defs
//#define USE_LL

#ifndef USE_LL
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#endif

#ifdef dummy_defs
#define QueuedAfterReading 1
typedef union _XEvent { int type; } XEvent;
void XNextEvent(void) {}
int XEventsQueued(void) {}
#endif


class XWin;

typedef void (XWin::*EventCallBack) (XEvent &event);

class XWin {

    static XWin * xparent;

protected:

    class Event {
        EventCallBack callBack_{};
        int event_{};
#ifdef USE_LL
        Event * next{};
#endif
    public:
        friend XWin;
        Event(int event, EventCallBack callBack);
        virtual ~Event(void){}

        void callBack(XEvent &x_event) {
            if (x_event.type == event_) (xparent->*callBack_)(x_event);
        }
    };

#ifdef USE_LL
    Event * events_{};
#else
    vector<Event *> events_{};
#endif

    inline void add_event(int event, EventCallBack callBack) {
#ifdef USE_LL
        Event * tmp;
        if (events_ == nullptr) events_ = new Event(event, callBack);
        else {
            tmp=events_;
            while (tmp->next) tmp=tmp->next;
            tmp->next=new Event(event, callBack);
        }
#else
        events_.emplace_back(new Event(event, callBack));
#endif
    }

    void checkevent(void);
};

XWin * XWin::xparent=nullptr;

void XWin::checkevent(void) {
    XEvent x_event;

    while (XEventsQueued()) {
        XNextEvent();

#ifdef USE_LL
        for (Event * tmp=events_; tmp; tmp=tmp->next)
            tmp->callBack(x_event);
#else
        for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->callBack)(x_event);
#endif
    }
}
```

The above (in C++ 11), gives the error:

```
test.cc: In member function ‘void XWin::checkevent()’:
test.cc:79:53: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘tmp->XWin::Event::callBack_ (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* tmp->XWin::Event::callBack_) (...)’
   for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->callBack_)(x_event);
                                                 ^
```

If I try to follow the error's "instructions", and add the '*', 
I get:

```
test.cc: In member function ‘void XWin::checkevent()’:
test.cc:79:36: error: ‘callBack_’ was not declared in this scope
   for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->*callBack)(x_event);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~
```

I.e. -- another error.  The first form "tmp->callBack_" seems to parallel the USE_LL case and given that 'tmp' is declared to be of type 'Event *', I'd think the accessing of a member in 'Event', would be of the same form, but the compiler complains not.

The program creates an event list that isn't modified after creation, so a basic 'array'-type container via an STL vector seemed the most efficient implementation.  Can someone point out why these two implementations aren't equivalent and how I should go about making them so (without the 'cure' being worse than the original)?

Thanks,
-Astara

p.s. fixed the vector case to call the proxy function 'callback' (had
callback_).  I had tried that, but somewhere it got modified.  I gives this error:

```
test.cc: In member function ‘void XWin::checkevent()’:
test.cc:79:36: error: ‘callBack’ was not declared in this scope
   for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->*callBack)(x_event);
                                    ^~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Start with a minimal compilable example of the problem. Your problems might not even be related to linked list or vector at all. We have less of an idea on how to debug your code then you do without something we can compile.

Comment: Why not `tmp->callBack(x_event);` as you did with the linked list version? Even gets around the problem you are going to have with `callBack_` being `private`.

Comment: @user4581301: Do you mean just removing the parens?  Christopher --I don't understand.  The first code section is a standalone -  stripped down example.  Are you saying it doesn't compile for you?

Comment: No, I mean linked list does `tmp->callBack(x_event);`but vector does `(tmp->callBack_)(x_event);` There is a proxy function involved in the linked list version.

Comment: oh... um... hmmm...fixed that... still gives a not-declared error

Comment: `callBack` and `callBack_` are two very different members...

Comment: OK. Now you don't want the brackets or the `*`: `tmp->callBack(x_event);`

Comment: The piece you were tripping over, by the way, is `tmp->*callBack_` was not looking for `callback_` in an `Event` instance, it was looking for it as an Automatic or in `XWin`. You would have needed something insano like `(tmp->*tmp->callBack_)(x_event);`, but I don't think that's quite right either.

Comment: General hint on writing questions: Please don't append edits that render previously written content obsolete. Instead rework you question to only present your actual/latest problem. You can modify your question as long as you didn't get an answer or you don't render existing answers wrong.

Comment: @honk Don't append edits that render previous content obsolete?  I didn't ... I did rework the problem to present the latest problem.  I am unclear -- should I modify the question to be the latest Q, or not modify it?  What answers have I rendered wrong?

Comment: You should read [How can I avoid syntax errors when calling a member function using a pointer-to-member-function?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#macro-for-ptr-to-memfn)

Comment: user4581310: I think your suggestion worked.. (minus the parens & star)...  @D Drmmr: interesting site -- but I'm not using C++17 yet and have never seen a std::invoke.  Perhaps it would have more easily solved the problem.  Also a prob -- the similarity between different things named some soft of event and similarity of the callBack_ var and 'callBack' function (I didn't choose the original names, but may change them -- just like I added use of 'x_event' (had been 'event')...

Comment: Your question presents an error and in your PS you claim that you have fixed it. IMHO there is never a need for an PS: You haven't written a letter on paper that can no longer be modified. Just directly update your original post and keep it as clean as possible. Readers will appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, @user4581301's comments were instrumental in solving what was, basically a semantic problem caused by the original design's over-use of similarly spelled names such as event v. event_ & events with some spellings being used for more than one type.  When I went to proofread the multiple variations made it difficult to see mistakes, and user4581301 pointed those out sufficiently for me to fix the problem.  Such confusion is one reason I'm trying to 'refactor' the code.  In case anyone wanted to see a corrected version, I'll post it here.

```
#define dummy_defs

/*
* The above question demonstrated the original code's use
* of a linked-list that one could 'test' by defining 'USE_LL'.
* The C++ STL implementation uses vector.  For clarity, I'll
* leave out the old LL code.
*/

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

// dummy defs to satisfy dependencies similarly to original code
#ifdef dummy_defs
typedef union _XEvent { int type; } XEvent;
void XNextEvent(void) {}
int XEventsQueued(void) {}
#endif


class XWin;

typedef void (XWin::*EventCallBack) (XEvent &event);

class XWin {

  static XWin * xparent;

protected:

  class Event {
    EventCallBack callBack_{};
    int event_{};
  public:
    friend XWin;
    Event(int event, EventCallBack callBack);
    virtual ~Event(void){}

    void callBack(XEvent &x_event) {
      if (x_event.type == event_) (xparent->*callBack_)(x_event);
    }
  };

  vector<Event *> events_{};

  inline void add_event(int event, EventCallBack callBack) { 
    events_.emplace_back(new Event(event, callBack));
  }

  void checkevent(void);
};

XWin * XWin::xparent=nullptr;

void XWin::checkevent(void) {
  XEvent x_event;

  while (XEventsQueued()) {
    XNextEvent();
    for (auto tmp:events_) tmp->callBack(x_event);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    Your code commented by me:

    #define dummy_defs
    //#define USE_LL
    #ifndef USE_LL
    #include <vector>  //object library type (might or not be an issue)
    using std::vector; // 'std' means 'provided' here
    #endif

    #ifdef dummy_defs
    #define QueuedAfterReading 1
    //your type definition
    typedef union _XEvent { 
    int type; 
    } 
    XEvent; 
    void XNextEvent(void) {
    }
    int XEventsQueued(void) {
    }
    #endif

    class XWin;
    //'asterisk' means you are using an 'address' for the value, not the value itself
    typedef void (XWin::*EventCallBack) (XEvent &event);
    //Your XWin class
    class XWin {

        static XWin * xparent;//'asterisk' means you are using an 'address' for the parent's value, not the value itself

    protected: //scope for the class below

        class Event {
            EventCallBack callBack_{
            };
            int event_{};
    #ifdef USE_LL
            Event * next{};//address of next() node, not the node itself
    #endif
        public: //scope for the block below
            friend XWin;
            Event(int event, EventCallBack callBack);//this function arguments are not the same as above, the underscore makes a difference
            virtual ~Event(void){}

            void callBack(XEvent &x_event) {
                if (x_event.type == event_) (xparent->*callBack_)(x_event);
            }
        };

    #ifdef USE_LL
        Event * events_{};
    #else
        vector<Event *> events_{};
    #endif

        inline void add_event(int event, EventCallBack callBack) {
    #ifdef USE_LL
            Event * tmp;
            if (events_ == nullptr) events_ = new Event(event, callBack);
            else {
                tmp=events_;
                while (tmp->next) tmp=tmp->next;
                tmp->next=new Event(event, callBack);
            }
    #else
            events_.emplace_back(new Event(event, callBack));
    #endif
        }

        void checkevent(void);
    };

    XWin * XWin::xparent=nullptr;

    void XWin::checkevent(void) {
        XEvent x_event;

        while (XEventsQueued()) {
            XNextEvent();

    #ifdef USE_LL
            for (Event * tmp=events_; tmp; tmp=tmp->next)
                tmp->callBack(x_event);
    #else
            for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->callBack)(x_event);
    #endif
        }
    }
    //Block with 'public:' scope and the related function into the class 'Event' whose scope is 'protected:' <--- , declared above
    (I think the PROBLEM IS HERE, check it and tell me).
    public: // <--- scope for the block below
            friend XWin;
            Event(int event, EventCallBack callBack);//this function arguments are not the same as above, the underscore makes a difference
            virtual ~Event(void){}

            void callBack(XEvent &x_event) {
                if (x_event.type == event_) (xparent->*callBack_)(x_event);
            }
        };

    The compiler error message before dereferencing:

        test.cc:79:53: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ <--- dereference needed ---> :) to call pointer-to-member function in ‘tmp->XWin::Event::callBack_ (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* tmp->XWin::Event::callBack_) (...)’
           for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->callBack_)(x_event);

    The compiler error message after dereferencing:

        test.cc: In member function ‘void XWin::checkevent()’:
        test.cc:79:36: error: ‘callBack_’ was not declared in this scope <--- 'scope' ---> :)
           for (Event * tmp:events_) (tmp->*callBack)(x_event);
```

Comment: Cristina Alonso: It's a bit confusing -- as I made edits in the '_' case to match the other, but the edits were reverted.  Then user4581301 mentioned 2 more changes, -- removing the parents and the '*'.  So those I tried in my code.  They worked.  I don't understand your comments -- what do you mean "object library type"?  Next line, what do you mean "std means  provided here"?    Using 'std::vector' says that vector is in the std library and that your code will be using the 'vector' class from the std lib in your code as 'vector' (no prefix).